# When I call "static void Example(int example)" and later on call "Example(Example);" The variable doesn't change

Tags: c#

When I create a `void` method and assign private variables to it, it usually works fine. But for some reason when I use this script below the `moveEnemy()` wont work properly. Im trying to make it so when the enemies position is greater than the players, the enemies position will decrease.

If I directly reference a variable the script works but not when I use the private ones. EX: using `posX += 1;` makes the enemy move forwards. But using `posX += speed` doesnt do anything at all even though in the `Main void` im changing both of those variables to `enemyPosX` and `enemySpeed`. What is wrong with the code?

```
static void moveEnemy(double posX, double posY, char symbol, double speed, bool made, bool move)
        {
            if (made == false)
            {
                posX = generateNumber.Next(defaultLeftBorder + 1, defaultRightBorder - 1);
                posY = generateNumber.Next(defaultUpBorder + 1, defaultDownBorder - 1);
                made = true;
                move = true;
            }

            if (posX > playerPosX + 1)
            {
                if (move == true)
                {
                    posX -= speed;
                    move = false;
                }
            }
            if (posX < playerPosX + 1)
            {
                if (move == true)
                {
                    posX += speed;
                    move = false;
                }
            }
            if (posY > playerPosY)
            {
                if (move == true)
                {
                    posY -= speed;
                    move = false;
                }
            }
            if (posY < playerPosY)
            {
                if (move == true)
                {
                    posY += speed;
                    move = false;
                }
            }
            drawEnemy(posX, posY, symbol);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            start();

            while (true)
            {
                moveEnemy(enemyPosX, enemyPosY, enemyChar, enemySpeed, enemyMade, enemyMove);

                Thread.Sleep(60);
                Console.Clear();
                enemyMove = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read about Pass by value and pass by reference. Add out or ref to your function parameters. That should solve it.

Comment: @Jawad - Sorry but your statement is misleading. Check what happens if you pass a List<T> to a function and then you do param = new List<T> within the function. You wont see the filled items once the function exits.

Comment: When including code please make sure it is a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); you don't provide the definitions of the `start()` method or `enemyPosX`, `enemyPosY`, etc. variables that are referenced in `Main()`.  In particular, you say `posX += 1;` works but `posX += speed;` does nothing, so I'm guessing `enemySpeed` is a field that never gets changed from its initial value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

> When I call “static void Example(int example)” and later on call
>   “Example(Example);” The variable doesn't change

Your title explains it.

**Problem:**

The below passes `example` by value. So whatever the lifecycle change in value of `example` within `Example()` method  is only limited within `Example()`'s scope. Anything outside of it will have the original value of `example`

`static void Example(int example)`

**Solution:**

Find it [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) .

This will improve your understanding on the topic as well. You need to pass `example` buy reference. So that whatever changes you make to the value of `example` within `Example(ref int example){ //Here }` will change the actual value of `example` in memory.